# Copy mule variable data or mule property like payload to spring bean property

Tags: java, spring, mule

I am having a mule flow in which I am having a variable to which payload is copied as follows:

```
<set-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable" doc:description="Variable having copy of original payload present in soap request."/>
```

After this there is an interceptor that validates header of soap message and if validation fails then I need the above variable's data in interceptor to prepare custom fault message. Below is my configuration for Soap Proxy doing above:

```
<cxf:proxy-service port="XXX" namespace="XXX" service="XXX" payload="body" wsdlLocation="XXXX" doc:name="SOAP" doc:description="Soap proxy intercept soap request and apply header validation. Authentication and custom header will be validated for presence, content, and structure.">
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <spring:bean id="XXXX" parent="XXXX">
            <spring:property name="sourceApplication" value="${sourceApplication}"/>
            <spring:property name="originalMessage" value="#[originalPayload]"/>
        </spring:bean>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
</cxf:proxy-service>
```

In above I need the value of originalPayload variable in originalMessage property of spring bean. If I can copy #[payload] directly it will work too. Above expression in spring property is not valid so it is not working.

Please suggest how to go for this.

Implementing Callable can be one option but I do not want to change the code written already unless there is no solution for above.

I tried to search for solution on this but could not find anything.

Thanks
Harish Kumar

Comment: not sure if it will work, but have you tried :

<spring:property name="originalMessage" value="#[groovy:payload]"/>
otherwiser i think it should be 

value="#[flowVars.originalPayload]" instead of value="#[originalPayload]"

Comment: @dunnless less I tried flowVars approach but it did not work. But thanks anyways for suggesting the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that spring properties are set at configuration time whereas the `#[payload]` expression could be only resolved at runtime.

However within your interceptor you could retrieve the original payload from the CXF message by doing something like this:

```
MuleEvent event = (MuleEvent) message.getExchange().get(CxfConstants.MULE_EVENT);
Collection<Attachment> a = event.getMessage().getInvocationProperty("originalPayload");
```

You can refer to [this interceptor](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/8de5e6b1de40e8d5f792e8e0f0b9d1de7506c2d8/modules/cxf/src/main/java/org/mule/module/cxf/support/CopyAttachmentOutInterceptor.java) as an example